# Is there a tool or library, similar to wkhtmltopdf, to convert html to word documents?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ms-word

It must be able to handle css and javascript as the page contains "highcharts" javascript charts.

It doesn't have to be an external process, a library would be great too.

Basically I need to be able to create a word document containing highcharts as images along with some text and other graphics.

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: you can do this within C# if you are using VisualStudio look at Microsoft.Interop services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this as an example

It depends a lot on the nature of the html document you are trying to convert. One simple way is just to use the Word automation to open an .html document and then save it as a .doc document.

```
        object readOnly = false;
        object isVisible = true;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value; // Values we don't care about
        object fileName = "C:/webpage.htm";
        object newFileName = "C:/webpage.doc";       

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        // word.Visible = true; // To see what's happening

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = word.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        document.Activate();

        object saveFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument;

        document.SaveAs(ref newFileName, ref saveFormat, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        document.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Note

- You have to add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word or something similar
- The number of *ref missing* arguments depends on wich version of Word you are using
- You have to use full paths in the filename as the Word instance starts from the System folder.

Comment: Thanks, will this take a URL as its input? And is word capable of handling dom elements created by javascript?

Comment: where it shows c:/webpage.htm or what ever the ext is replace with a URL you may or may not have to do some URL Encoding.. you will have to experiment with this for what ever your use case is.. this is something to get you started in or on the right direction.. also pay close attention to the Notes listed above in the bullets

Comment: I hope this helps ...feel free to Vote Up

Comment: this is unable to render the charts

Comment: what code do you have .. can't tell what you ar doing unless I see what it is that you have written thanks